# How do you pack the MONO Runtime with your application?

Tags: c#, .net, mono, runtime, portability

I hate how .NET Programs want you to download the .NET Framework to run them , so I was thinking of embedding the MONO Runtime with my program. Is there any third party software for doing it easily or would I need to do it by hand or by C/C++? Also , how much extra hard drive space would it need and are there any disadvantages of doing this?

P.S If I need to do it with C/C++, can you give me some example code?

Comment: The point of downloading the .NET Framework is to have the latest version with all patches applies. Even if you prefer the Mono, you should go for an installer that downloads the latest Mono version rather than bundle an out-dated version with your application. Note that most operating systems already come with a version of the .NET Framework or Mono that is kept up to date using the operating system's update mechanism.

Comment: Some of my clients don't have fast internet connections, i was thinking of an offline solution. Also, is there anyway toguide them in downloading .NET (like a message box "You need .NET Framework v2.0 to run this application. Do you want to download it now?")

Comment: Have a look at [smallestdotnet](http://www.hanselman.com/smallestdotnet/).

Comment: Thanks, But is it legal to distribute the .NET Framework offline installer with my app?

Comment: Yes, the Microsoft .NET Framework 4 redistributable packages are meant to be distributed alongside your application.

Comment: Yay!Thanks! Post your comment as an answer and i'll tick and upvote it! ^_^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can distribute the Microsoft .NET Framework 4 redistributable package alongside your application.

Have a look at [smallestdotnet.com](http://www.hanselman.com/smallestdotnet/).

Answer (score 4):

Interesting idea - it looks like Mr. Icaza has documented exactly how to do that [here](http://www.mono-project.com/Embedding_Mono).

Comment: Thanks! But isnt there any third party tool which does it easily without all those libraries and linking?

Answer (score 0):

This question is an old one. But it's the first link to the StackOverflow that Google gave me.

So for anyone else who lands here after googling:

- Take a look at the [mkbundle](http://www.mono-project.com/archived/guiderunning_mono_applications/#bundles) utility that is a part of the Mono project's SDK.
- And see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20490328/818321) for more details.