# Does Mono Mkbundle Produce Native Code

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop, xamarin-studio

The normal EXE's generated by mono are in IL.I want to generate Native Executable,does using mkbundle produce native Exe's or should i use Mono AOT.

Answer (score 15):

Yes, mkbundle produces native executables.
For example, on Linux, here is my .NET assembly:

```
file Agent.exe
Agent.exe: PE32 executable (console) Intel 80386, Mono/.Net assembly, for MS Windows
```

I tell `mkbundle` to compile it to a native executable (here I have to add Common.dll which is a dependency to my Agent.exe assembly):

```
mkbundle --deps -o Agent Agent.exe Common.dll
   OS is: Linux
   Sources: 3 Auto-dependencies: True
   embedding: Agent/bin/Debug/Agent.exe
   embedding: Agent/bin/Debug/Common.dll
   embedding: /usr/lib/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll
   embedding: /usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Runtime.Serialization/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Runtime.Serialization.dll
   embedding: /usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Xml/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
   embedding: /usr/lib/mono/gac/System/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
   embedding: /usr/lib/mono/gac/Mono.Security/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/Mono.Security.dll
   embedding: /usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Configuration/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
   embedding: /usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Security/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Security.dll
   embedding: /usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Core/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
   embedding: /usr/lib/mono/gac/Mono.Posix/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/Mono.Posix.dll
   embedding: /usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Data.Linq/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.Linq.dll
   embedding: /usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Data/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll
   embedding: /usr/lib/mono/gac/Mono.Data.Tds/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/Mono.Data.Tds.dll
   embedding: /usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Transactions/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Transactions.dll
   embedding: /usr/lib/mono/gac/System.EnterpriseServices/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.EnterpriseServices.dll
Compiling:
as -o temp.o temp.s 
cc -ggdb -o Agent -Wall temp.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs mono-2`  temp.o
Done
```

Now, Let's run the `file` command again, this time against the generated 'Agent' binary:

```
file Agent
Agent: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=698384c13208eccc609e5a573deeb09ed3420a29, not stripped
```

Note : this native binary still depends on libmono (the Mono runtime library), so it won't work on a machine without a working Mono installation.

You can however embed libmono into your binary and get an independant, self-contained executable by using mkbundle `--static` option.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.So if i use mkbundle in windows it will produce a exe file with native code rather than ILCODE right? In case of .net i has used obfuscation for protection should i use it too?

Comment: Yes, that's the point of using mkbundle. But I cannot help you about how to run it on Windows (I don't use it), I only know that you'll have to install the Mingw compiler and Cygwin before using mkbundle.

Comment: Is this option available in the UI on Visual Studio for Mac?

Answer (score 3):

- http://www.mono-project.com/archived/guiderunning_mono_applications/#bundles

> *mkbundle* generates an executable program that will contain static copies of the assemblies listed on the command line.

I doubt this is what you expected from a word "native exe."  Here's a small experiment:

`Test01.cs`

```cs
using System;
public class Test01 {
  public static void Main()
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Hello, world!");
    Console.WriteLine("Hello, world!");
    Console.WriteLine("Hello, world!");
  }
}
```

The output MSIL should contain three pairs of `ldstr` and `call` instructions, and the terminating `ret` instruction.  Their opcodes are 0x72, 0x28 and 0x2a, respectively:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes_fields%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Let's check the hex dump (`grep -P` allows us to use non-greedy match `*?`)

```
$ od -t x1 -w9999999 Test01.exe | grep -o -P 72.*?28.*?2a
...
72 01 00 00 70 28 01 00 00 0a 72 01 00 00 70 28 01 00 00 0a 72 01 00 00 70 28 01 00 00 0a 2a
```

Now we know the MSIL byte sequence corresponding to the above `Test01.cs`.  And the output from `mkbundle` contains exactly the same byte sequence:

```
$ mkbundle -o Test01 Test01.exe --deps
...
$ od -t x1 -w9999999 Test01 | fgrep -o '72 01 00 00 70 28 01 00 00 0a 72 01 00 00 70 28 01 00 00 0a 72 01 00 00 70 28 01 00 00 0a 2a'
72 01 00 00 70 28 01 00 00 0a 72 01 00 00 70 28 01 00 00 0a 72 01 00 00 70 28 01 00 00 0a 2a
```

Unfortunately I don't think `mkbundle(1)` has any options like `--full-aot`.  So AOT and creating a (static) bundle exe is mutually exclusive as of now (Mono 4.2.2.30)

Comment: By native i mean platform specific code.. not IL Code.What i mean is .. will i get a binary like the one generated by a c compiler ?

Comment: Again, I don't think you can use `mkbundle` and AOT at the same time, but you might have a better solution at mono-list@lists.ximian.com

Comment: He's right, all it does is directly copy the .dll and .exe files into an assembly, it doesn't compile them to machine code