# Mono and Winforms: Making .exe Runnable for Others

Tags: winforms, macos, mono

I'm new to Mono and Mac OS development as a whole. I wrote a C#/WinForms application on my PC, and using:

```
mcs Form1.cs ...
mono Form1.exe
```

My executable runs. I want to be able to run this executable (or some other type of file) directly, on another Mac without Mono. How do I go about this?

Comment: I have updated my answer with information about mkbundle tool. It may be a way to go for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Applications written in C# cannot be executed without Mono runtime or .NET Framework**. It is exactly the same situation as we are experiencing with Java applications - we cannot run Java apps without the JRE (Java Runtime Environment) installed.

You may have noticed that there are two versions of Mono available for Mac OS X:

1. **MDK** (Mono Development Kit)
   It is needed only if you want to build applications from source code.
2. **MRE** (Mono Runtime Environment)
   It is noticeably smaller than MDK and it is required in order to execute applications compiled with MDK.

If you cannot install MRE on the target machine then you will have to choose different programming language. Preferably one that does not need runtime environment to be installed - for example C/C++.

**EDIT:** I have just found that MDK contains a tool called **mkbundle** which packages an exe and all assemblies with libmono into a single binary package. Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20490328/3325704) for more information.